# R Use map2 to iterate over columns within a list of data frames to fit statistical models

Tags: r, mapping, purrr

I'm trying to figure out a purrr approach to iteratively map over columns within a list of data frames to fit univariate GLMs. Using `map2`, the first element, `.x`, would be the three pred columns, and the second element, `.y`, would be the list of data frames (or vice-versa). `map2` seems to be able to do this, but I recognize that I need to cross the .x and .y elements first, so I use `tidyr::crossing` first to do this. From here, I am unsure how to properly reference the columns to select within the data frames. Example code is below:

```
#Sample data
set.seed(100)
test_df <- tibble(pred1 = sample(40:80, size = 1000, replace = TRUE),
                  pred2 = sample(40:80, size = 1000, replace = TRUE),
                  pred3 = sample(40:80, size = 1000, replace = TRUE),
                  resp = sample(100:200, size = 1000, replace = TRUE),
                  group = sample(c('a','b','c'), size = 1000, replace = TRUE))

#Split into list
test_ls <- test_df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  {df_groups <<- .} %>% 
  group_split()

#Obtain keys and name list elements
group_keys <- df_groups %>% 
  group_keys() %>% 
  pull()

test_ls <- test_ls %>% setNames(nm = group_keys)

#Cross all combinations of pred columns and list element names
preds <- c('pred1','pred2','pred3')
map_keys <- crossing(preds, group_keys) 

#.y = list of data frames; iterate over data frames
#.x = three pred columns; iterate over columns
#Use purrr to fit glm of each .x columns within each of .y dfs

#Example structure - does not work
map2(.x, .y, .f = ~glm(resp ~ .x, data = .y))

#Workaround that does work
lapply(test_ls, function(x) {
  x %>% 
    select(pred1, pred2, pred3) %>% 
    map(.f = ~glm(resp ~ .x, data = x))
})
```

There's something I'm missing, and I can't seem to figure it out. I've gotten a variety of errors with a few approaches, but I think it's coming down to not properly referencing the `.x` columns within the `.y` data frames. My approaches don't seem to recognize that `.x` is a column within `.y`. The workaround does the trick, but I'd prefer to avoid using both `lapply` and `map`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to NOT split the data before fitting models, since you are considering all possible combinations of variables that are already available directly in your original dataset. Instead, consider converting the original data frame to the "long" format, and then grouping by the necessary variables:

```
test_df %>% gather( pred, value, pred1:pred3 ) %>%
  nest( -c(group, pred) ) %>%
  mutate( models = map(data, ~glm(resp ~ value, data=.x)) )
# # A tibble: 9 x 4
#   group pred  data               models
#   <chr> <chr> <list>             <list>
# 1 b     pred1 <tibble [340 x 2]> <glm> 
# 2 a     pred1 <tibble [317 x 2]> <glm> 
# 3 c     pred1 <tibble [343 x 2]> <glm> 
# 4 b     pred2 <tibble [340 x 2]> <glm> 
# 5 a     pred2 <tibble [317 x 2]> <glm> 
# 6 c     pred2 <tibble [343 x 2]> <glm> 
# 7 b     pred3 <tibble [340 x 2]> <glm> 
# 8 a     pred3 <tibble [317 x 2]> <glm> 
# 9 c     pred3 <tibble [343 x 2]> <glm>
```

This substantially simplifies your code, and you can now split the result, if you still need those models in a list.

Comment: This the exact solution I eventually figured out once I learned how to use list columns. Thank you for underscoring it as the purrr friendly solution. I used tidyr::pivot_longer to dplyr::group_by to tidyr::nest, but it's the same process.